# The command sudo i2cdetect is not recognized

Tags: i2c

When I try to use "sudo i2cdetect -y 1" it comes back with unknown command. I turned on i2c do I need to download any new software?

Comment: You don't need the sudo if you are using Raspbian and the user is a member of the i2c group.  Your particular problem is as identified by goldilocks though.

Comment: Although user `pi` is part of the group `i2c` in my case, I still have to run `i2cdetect` with `sudo` in front of it.  Running RPi 3B+ using `stretch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Raspbian (and other Debian derivatives) `i2cdetect` is in package `i2c-tools`.

```
sudo apt install i2c-tools
```

The package has the same name in Fedora, so I would guess other distros as well.